# Does <table> behave differently compared to <ul> or <div> when trying to get a collection of their children tags? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, list, html-table

I'm trying to make a generic JavaScript function to obtain a collection of entries within a tag. For example:

With a list

```
<ul class="collection">
    <li>First Entry</li>
    <li>Second Entry</li>
    <li>Third Entry</li>
</ul>
```

With divs

```
<div class="collection">
    <div >First Entry</div >
    <div >Second Entry</div >
    <div >Third Entry</div >
</div>
```

With tables

```
<table class="collection">
    <tr>First Entry</tr>
    <tr>Second Entry</tr>
    <tr>Third Entry</tr>
</table>
```

Here's what I have:

```
function getEntry(a)
{
    var elementCollection = document.getElementsByTagName('*');

    for(var i = 0; i < elementCollection.length; i++)
    {
        if(elementCollection[i].className.toString() === "collection")
        {
            var filteredCollection = elementCollection[i].children;

            alert(filteredCollection[a].innerHTML);
        }
    }
}
```

This does exactly what I want if I deal with lists or divs, but when I run that through a table he gives the me all entries if a=0 or nothing if a!=0

Do tables behave differently or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It's not valid HTML to have text content as a child of `tr` (it needs to be inside a `th` or `td`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, your HTML is invalid because it doesn't include a `<tbody>` element, so the browser is inserting it for you, as is the case with the table cells.

So when you get to your `table`, and use `.children[0]`, you're getting the new `<tbody>` element, which contains all the `<tr>` elements, which explains why it gives you all the entries.

And of course if you use `.children[1]` or anything greater than `0`, there is no child because you only have the one `tbody`.

Comment: `table.cells` will give you the `th` and `td` elements.

Comment: I see. So the only way to circle around this without changing the HTML would be to look for the exception (the tables) and do .children[0].children[a]?

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli: Yep, that's noted in my answer.

Comment: I didn't include the the <td> tags because they didn't matter for this example (I think).

Comment: @dosaki: there can be multiple `<tbody>` elements, as well as a `<thead>` and `<tbody>` element, so if you don't know the layout of the page, you may just want to test for tables, and use `table.rows` to get all the rows directly. `table.rows[0]`

Comment: @IHateLazy right, I should have been more explicit: `foo.rows[0].cells`